# Is there a way to send sign in instructions email via google api?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I am integrating my application with google api to automate the user creation process .

I am using [directory-api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) for creating users . I want to send a sign in instructions mail that we send after creating a user in google workspace . in google admin .  here is a image of it [link](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/manage-users-google-workspace-email.png)

Is there way to send such email via api . kindly tell me .

Answer (score 0):

I found [this blog](https://community.looker.com/technical-tips-tricks-1021/creating-users-and-sending-custom-welcome-emails-via-api-29973) with a workaround for this. You can review it and see if that works for you.

They are basically using the [messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) method from the Gmail API to send the message. You can also review the Google Guide (it has an example in Java and Python) on how to [send email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) using the Gmail API in the Google documentation.